# Meaing of "And still for all our talk"

Tags: translation

Would you please help me get to the bottom of the meaing of quite a vague phrase "And still for all our talk"? Again, it is a part of G. Hansard´s song Bird of Sorrow. Thank you.

Comment: Can you provide more context? Like the entire paragraph where you found this? Also, what kind of book is _Bird of Sorrow_?

Comment: The expression: For all our [talk, discussion, conversation, etc.] means: despite all our talk, [you still think blah blah blah, for example]

Comment: Oh I see! Pls find the context in the lyrics at http://lyricstranslate.com/en/glen-hansard-bird-sorrow-lyrics.html

Answer (score 1):

> Come on, we gotta get out, get out of this mess we made
>
> And still, **for all our talk**, we're both so afraid.
>
> Will we leave this up to chance like we do everything?

Hopefully the phrase is less confusing with the comma I inserted after "still".  It could be rewritten "For all (of) our talk, we (are) both still so afraid."

"For all our talk" implies that "we" often talk as if we are *not* afraid, but in spite of all that, we still *are* afraid.  In this case, "for" means "despite".

Comment: My friend, you are briliant! Your explanation is exhaustive! Thank you very much. Greetings from Czech Rep., Venda

Comment: My personal favorite song by Glen Hansard is ["Broken Hearted Hoover Fixer Sucker Guy"](https://vimeo.com/25951843).  It's a very simple song, yet funny because "sucker" can refer to how Hoover vacuum cleaners "suck" up dirt, and also because ["sucker" means "a fool easily deceived"](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/sucker)